# Event isn't triggered

Tags: c#, .net, events, event-handling

I have created an event called `textBox1_Leave`; But when I run my program, and I move the focus from `txtBox1` the event isn't triggered.

I would like this event to be triggered, so I can check if the `Name` value that the user enters in `txtBox1` exists in my database. If it does, I want to enable `button1` by setting `button1.Enable = true` and otherwise to `false`.

My C# Code:

```
private void textBox1_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OleDbConnection A=new OleDbConnection();
    A.ConnectionString=Program.DBPATH;
    A.Open();

    OleDbCommand BB=new OleDbCommand();
    BB.Connection=A;
    BB.CommandText="SELECT username FROM Users WHERE (username = '" + textBox1.Text + "')";
    OleDbDataReader CC = BB.ExecuteReader();

    if (CC.Read())
    {
        button1.Enabled=true;
    }
    else
    {
        button1.Enabled=false;
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens when you step through it with the debugger?  If nothing, then the event sounds like it isn't wired up: put `textBox1.Leave += textBox1_Leave;` in the form's constructor.

Comment: what does 'nothing happens' mean? that your event handler is not entered at all, or that DB is not called and button state modified?

Comment: If the event is not getting called at all then most likely the problem is the event handler is properly registered of you are not actually  leaving.  Just moving the mouse out not fire the event.  Doesn't work nothing happens is vague.  Provide more information or this question will get closed.

Comment: Maybe you should use the TextChanged event.

Answer (score 2):

```
first check the event is wired up in constructor of the page

textBox1.Leave += textBox1_Leave;


and then

1) Debug the program and check whether break point is hitting.
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are developing windows application.
I would suggest you to go through following steps:

1) Debug the program and check whether break point is hitting.

2) On your form you should have some control other than the textbox , then only the Leave event will fire. If you are having only textbox on the form the Leave event of textbox would not fire.

3) use try catch block else your application will crash if there is runtime error.